# C# Close stream on Directory.Enumerate or XElement.Load

Tags: c#, io, filesystems

If I'm using static methods in system classes that essentially use a stream, how can I close them in my finally block? Do I even need to?

```
try{
    List<string> fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, searchString)
                                .OrderByDescending(filename => filename)
                                .where(filename => filename.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml")
                                .ToList();
}
catch(Exception e){
    throw new Exception("Could not enumerate files.", e);
}
finally{
    //Close the stream?
}

try{
    XElement data = XElement.Load(pathToFile);
}
catch(Exception e){
    throw new Exception("Could not load xml file.", e);
}
finally{
    //Close the stream? The XmlReader?
}
```

That's just a couple of examples I ran into, there are probably more.

Comment: you can close the code inside using block so that the instance will automatically dispose
.

Comment: @Koderzzzz, but it's not an instance, these are static methods of a system class. No instance needed or used.

Comment: Go [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) and check. If it's not returning any `IDisposable` then it's closing it by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard libraries, by design, everything that gets an `IDisposable` object as a parameter is not disposing that object. But since you've mentioned `static` methods which aren't taking any `IDisposable` object as an input and returns an arbitrary "non-disposable" object, are used and disposed as well inside of that call.

Example for [`XElement.Load(string)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,4ee76e346bed5a3a) :

```
// https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,4ee76e346bed5a3a
public static XElement Load(string uri, LoadOptions options) { 
    XmlReaderSettings rs = GetXmlReaderSettings(options);
    using (XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(uri, rs)) {
        return Load(r, options);
    }
}
```

As you can see it disposes `XmlReader`.

But if you go for [`XElement.Load(XmlReader, LoadOptions)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,48dbb04c09f7b209,references) instead :

```
public static XElement Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) {
    if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("reader");
    if (reader.MoveToContent() != XmlNodeType.Element) throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString(Res.InvalidOperation_ExpectedNodeType, XmlNodeType.Element, reader.NodeType));
    XElement e = new XElement(reader, options);
    reader.MoveToContent();
    if (!reader.EOF) throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString(Res.InvalidOperation_ExpectedEndOfFile));
    return e;
}
```

You can see that it does not dispose stream passed by the parameter.